# Refresh RecyclerView in realtime after adding new data to sqLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-recyclerview, android-sqlite

I'm trying to refresh an activity with recyclerview every time SQLite get new data ( actually SQLite get the data from a TCP client signal ) 
here is my RecyclerView code :

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView data_txt;
    public TextView text_txt;
    public TextView ora_txt;
    public ImageView img;

    public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        data_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Data);
        ora_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Ora);
        text_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Errore);
        img = itemView.findViewById(R.id.error_photo);
    }

}
private List<Adapter> mText;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context c,List<Adapter> testo) {
    this.c = c;
    mText = testo;

}


@Override
public RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View contactView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_blueprint, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(contactView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    Adapter adapter = mText.get(position);

    TextView mData = viewHolder.data_txt;
    mData.setText(adapter.getDataText());

    TextView mOra = viewHolder.ora_txt;
    mOra.setText(adapter.getOraText());

    TextView mTesto = viewHolder.text_txt;
    mTesto.setText(adapter.getTesto());

    ImageView mImg = viewHolder.img;
    mImg.setImageBitmap(adapter.getImage());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mText.size();
}

public void removeItem(int position) {

    Adapter a = mText.get(position);
    int id=a.getId();

     DataBaseHandler myDB;
     myDB = DataBaseHandler.getInstance(c);
    myDB.openDB();
    if(myDB.delete(id))
    {
        mText.remove(position);
    }else
    {
        Toast.makeText(c,"Unable To Delete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    myDB.closeDB();
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

When i'm trying to update RecyclerView with `RecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` when the TCP server get the data that crash with error :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.sguidetti.selfmanegment.RecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()' on a null object reference
```

EDIT : 
Here is code where i call notifyDataSetChande() in TCP server class :

```
    Vibrator vibrator;
    String date,ora;
    long[] pattern = {0, 1000, 500, 1000, 500, 1000};

    int lun;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        InputStream leggi;
        try {


            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(socketServerPORT);

            while (true) {
                myDB = DataBaseHandler.getInstance(activity);

                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                leggi = socket.getInputStream();
                byte[] data = new byte[1000];
                lun = leggi.read(data, 0, data.length);
                letto = new String(data, "UTF-8");
                count++;
                MediaPlayer mPlay = MediaPlayer.create(activity, R.raw.gabsuono);
                mPlay.start();

                vibrator = (Vibrator) activity.getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                vibrator.vibrate(pattern, -1);

                date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(new Date());
                ora = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());



                myDB.insertDataServer(date, ora, letto);

                adapterView.notifyDataSetChanged();

                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        prefs = activity.getSharedPreferences("MY_DATA", MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
                        edit.putInt("counter", count);
                        edit.commit();
                        activity.msg.setText(String.valueOf(count));
                        activity.msg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }
                });
                leggi.close();


            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

and here is the activity where i call the RecyclerView:

```
DataBaseHandler myDB;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerViewAdapter adapterView;
ImageButton home;
String IMGSTRING;
Adapter adapter;
List<Adapter> textList;
private Paint p = new Paint();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_allert);
    Utils.darkenStatusBar(this, R.color.colorAccent);
    myDB = DataBaseHandler.getInstance(this);
    home = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.casa);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    Bitmap img;
    img = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.allert);
    Cursor data = myDB.fetchDataServer();
    textList = new ArrayList<>();
    int cont = 0;
    if (data.getCount() != 0) {
        while (data.moveToNext()) {


            IMGSTRING = data.getString(3).substring(0, 3);


            switch (IMGSTRING) {
                case "X00":
                    img = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.allert);
                    break;
                case "E01":
                    img = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.e01);
                    break;
                case "E02":
                    img = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.e02);
                    break;
                case "E03":
                    img = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.e03);
                    break;
                case "E90":
                    img = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.e90);
                    break;
                case "E04":
                    img = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.e04);
                    break;
                case "E05":
                    img = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.e04);
                    break;
                case "E06":
                    img = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.e04);
                    break;
            }


            adapter = new Adapter(data.getInt(0), data.getString(1), data.getString(2), data.getString(3).substring(3), img);   // 1 = time 2 = data 3 = text


            textList.add(cont, adapter);
            cont++;

        }
        RecyclerViewAdapter recycler = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, textList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recycler);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager((new LinearLayoutManager(this)));
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(allert.this, "NESSUN MESSAGGIO DA VISUALIZZARE!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    adapterView = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, textList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterView);
    adapterView.notifyDataSetChanged();
    initSwipe();
    home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            finish();
        }
    });
}

private void initSwipe() {
    ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleItemTouchCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {

        @Override
        public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
            int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
            adapterView.removeItem(position);


        }

        @Override
        public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {

            Bitmap icon;
            if (actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_SWIPE) {

                View itemView = viewHolder.itemView;
                float height = (float) itemView.getBottom() - (float) itemView.getTop();
                float width = height / 3;

                p.setColor(Color.parseColor("#D32F2F"));
                RectF background = new RectF((float) itemView.getRight() + dX, (float) itemView.getTop(), (float) itemView.getRight(), (float) itemView.getBottom() - 10);
                c.drawRect(background, p);
                icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_delete_white);
                RectF icon_dest = new RectF((float) itemView.getRight() - 2 * width, (float) itemView.getTop() + width, (float) itemView.getRight() - width, (float) itemView.getBottom() - width);
                c.drawBitmap(icon, null, icon_dest, p);

            }
            super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
        }
    };
    ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(simpleItemTouchCallback);
    itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}
```

Comment: Call `notifyDataSetChanged` from  Fragment in which you are using  RecyclerView

Comment: from where are you calling "notifyDataSetChanged()"? You need to ensure your reference to the adapter is not null is all. I would investigate where the call is made.

Comment: There is yet an notifyDataSetChange in layout where i use it but still doesn't work, i mean when i'm in that activity for update new RecyclerView messages i have to exit from that activity and enter in it again. ( sorry for my bad english )

Comment: `ViewHolder.notiftyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: @paligap i'm calling it from TCP server activity i mean the recyclerView have to refresh after a TCP client signal has been sent.

Comment: Your Adpater  is not assigned yet, when you calling adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() in your activity. Make sure it is initialized.

Comment: You're calling it from the TCP server activity, you must have the adapter encapsulated in a variable that is not null. Can you confirm that the variable is not null when you make the call to 'notifyDataSetChanged()'?

As other responders have alerted to, you are making the correct call for your requirement, just ensure the variable is NOT null when you make the call to refresh the adapter.

Comment: @paligap actually the variable is null because i need an empty variable when initialized i mean idk how to make it's empty but not null...

Comment: I think adapterview object in adapterView.notifyDataSetChanged() is null  which is inside your tcp code.

Comment: still nothing, i was trying to refresh the Allert activity ( activity where i get RecyclerView ) by closing and reopening it on TCP signal but still giving the same null error also if i don't use notifyDataSetChanged what the hell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you have a null check here?

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mText != null ? mText.size() : 0;
}
```

My best guess of the reason is you call notifyDataSetChanged() when mText is still null. When notifyDataSetChanged() is called, getItemCount() will be called first to check if the current position on the list is within the size of your "mText" list but it will get a crash as mText is null.

Two things you could improve on removeItem() method:

1. Instead of calling this.notifyDataSetChanged(), call this.notifyItemRemoved(position) as onBindViewHolder() will not be called n times (n = number of rows currently visible in your RecyclerView)
2. Don't mix your database code with your UI code. Your RecyclerView.Adapter class should only be concerned with UI logic and UI state objects (in this case, mText). In other words,

   ```
   public void removeItem(int position) {
       mText.remove(position);
       this.notifyItemRemoved(position);
   }
   ```

In your MainActivity class, call removeItem() in addition to your database code.

Comment: Yeah actually mText in RecyclerViewAdapter and in Adapter is null and that will fill just in another acitivity getting data from database, how could i fix it? because i actually need to initialize that mText as empty...

Comment: Maybe have an asynchronous callback and only call this.notifyDataSetChanged() in your callback's success method? (Before passing data to mText, of course)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure adapter is initialized before calling notifyDataSetChanged() method. An alternate approach is to add a method in adapter class in which you may pass the ArrayList and call notifyDataSetChanged() ;

Comment: could you make an example of the ArrayList please?

Comment: /**
     * Method in adapter add latest notifications received from database.
     * @param notificationsArrayList
     */

public void updateAdapter(List<Notifications> notificationsArrayList){
        try {
            Logger.logd("Size " ,notificationsList.size()+"");          
            notificationsList.addAll(notificationsArrayList);
           notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



Add this in Activity.
notificationsListRecycleAdapter.updateAdapter(notificationsList);